# Test simple Rxjava and gradle code get error?

Tags: java, gradle, rx-java

I wrote a simple Rxjava code with java and gradle, but I got some error, the details as follows:

This is my Simple java source code:

```
import rx.functions.Action1;
import rx.Observable;
public class HelloWorld{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        hello("Wjm");
    }

    public static void hello(String... names){
        Observable.from(names).subscribe(new Action1<String>(){

            @Override
            public void call(String s){
                System.out.println("Hello " +s +"!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my gradle.build source code:

```
apply plugin: 'java'


jar{
    manifest{
        attributes 'Main-Class':'HelloWorld'

    }

}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://oss.jfrog.org/libs-snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
    runtime 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0'
}
```

This is my project structure:

```
.
├── build
│   ├── classes
│   │   └── main
│   │       ├── HelloWorld$1.class
│   │       └── HelloWorld.class
│   ├── dependency-cache
│   ├── libs
│   │   └── proj1.jar
│   └── tmp
│       ├── compileJava
│       │   └── emptySourcePathRef
│       └── jar
│           └── MANIFEST.MF
├── build.gradle
└── src
    └── main
        └── java
            └── HelloWorld.java
```

I run the command "gradle build" is successful, However, 
when i run "java -jar proj1.jar" in the build/libs/ path, and I got the error message as follows:

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: rx/functions/Action1
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: rx.functions.Action1
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I am a fresh in gradle, so i asked, but i do a test in android studio, same java code, and run successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added the dependency correctly but.. when you run the application via jar prepared with gradle the dependency is missing. Why? Because you didn't configure the classpath for the jar being run correctly. To fix it you need to either:

1. Use [shadow plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) and prepare the jar in such a way that all the dependencies will repackaged and included into resulting jar. This is done with `shadowJar` task.
2. Configure classpath manually when the prepared jar is run. E.g.:

   ```
   java -cp ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.reactivex/rxjava/1.1.0/748f0546d5c3c27f1aef07270ffea0c45f0c42a4/rxjava-1.1.0.jar:build/libs/37183502.jar org.opal.Elo
   ```
3. Use gradle [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) and run the main class with `gradle clean run`. Application plugin can also prepare some distributions with scripts to run them.

Have a look at the [demo](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/37183502).

Comment: Thanks, that's help me a lot. And the demo is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not the best answer but it works for me.

I just downloaded all jar libraries that my project needed and put them in root of my project (or you can create a LIB directory and put them there) and just run the command below in the root of my project :

`java -cp *:directory_of_my_jar/my_output_jar.jar Main`

where "Main" is the main class of your project. if you put main class in package , write the package and class name , for example : com.example.Main

`java -cp *:directory_of_my_jar/my_output_jar.jar com.example.Main`